# Ip Address is not returning on rquesting cdpCacheAddress in snmp, instead showing c0:a8:0a:xX

Tags: snmp, cisco, discovery, snmp4j, oid

i did a **snmpwalk** code in **java** , to retrieve data associated with **cdp cache**. except **cdpCacheAddress**, every thing is showing as expected. cdpCacheAddress is expected as IP but shows as **c0:a8:0a:xX** . the oid i requested is begins with .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.4. how can i find the ip address of the neighbor with this data. is there any other way to find the neighbor's IP address with cdp .
please help.

Comment: That is just the hex representation of 192.168.10.xX .

Comment: Don't answer in comments please @Gambit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *is* an IP address.

It's four octets, each shown in hex, delimited by colons. It could also be rendered as "192.168.10.xX".

The syntax [is defined](http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/MIBS/?oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.4) to be a [`CiscoNetworkAddress`](https://www.cisco.com/iam/PGW_MIBS/922/tc.my) (whose definition includes the `DISPLAY-HINT` that results in the default rendering you see), so you should interpret it as such.

You can transform & display it however you like!

How to do that depends entirely on your language/environment.